# How is it possible to safely copy an int into a byte array unaligned?

Tags: c++, memory-management, alignment

I created a byte array, `uint8_t data[256]`, and I would like to read and write data to it at arbitrary positions. The position offset could be any number, so it could result in an unaligned access. For example if `sizeof(int32_t) == 4` then `position % sizeof(int32_t) != 0`

It works now but, as far as I know, some platforms do not directly support unaligned access. I would like to make it work in that case as well.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

void write(uint8_t* data, uint32_t position, int32_t value) {
    int32_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&data[position]);
    
    *ptr = value;
}

int32_t read(uint8_t* data, uint32_t position) {
    int32_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&data[position]);
    
    return *ptr;
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t data[256];
    int32_t value = 123456789;
    uint32_t position = 1; // Example for unaligned access

    write(data, position, value);
    
    int32_t read_value = read(data, position);
    
    std::cout << read_value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I prefer to use the standard library, if there is a solution there for this problem.

Comment: Use `std::memcpy` to copy the bytes into an `int32_t result;`, then return that `result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no placement `new` in your code, making both `reinterpret_cast`s undefined behaviour.
**The returned pointer can only be dereferenced if at the given address exists an object of the specified type.** With exception of `char`, `std::byte`, `unsigned char` which can always be dereferenced.

The safe way how to serialize and deserialize objects is through `std::memcpy`:

```
void write(unsigned char* data, uint32_t position, int32_t value) {
   
    std::memcpy(data+position,&value,sizeof(value));
}

int32_t read(unsigned char* data, uint32_t position) { 
    int32_t result;
    std::memcpy(&result,data+position,sizeof(result));
    return result;
}
```

This also solves any aligment issues.

Comment: Correct. Modern compilers (at least in optimized builds) should recognize what happens here. E.g. https://www.godbolt.org/z/7r9ePfT9c - x64 doesn't have a problem with unaligned access,, so it just loads the int.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid possible issues of violating [strict aliasing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Strict_aliasing), you can use the [`std::memcpy` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

```cpp
#include <cstring> // For std::memcpy

void write(uint8_t* data, uint32_t position, int32_t value)
{
    std::memcpy(&data[position], &value, sizeof(value));
}

int32_t read(uint8_t* data, uint32_t position)
{
    int answer;
    std::memcpy(&answer, &data[position], sizeof(answer));
    return answer;
}
```

From the (second) linked cppreference page:

> Where strict aliasing prohibits examining the same memory as values of
> two different types, `std::memcpy` may be used to convert the values.