Is reinterpret_cast from char* to uint32_t* undefined behaviour in CPP?
I work on a medium-sized open source project which requires interpreting raw bytes as different types. This is performed by creative use of reinterpret casting. However, in a simple test case, compiling with GCC 10 or above with optimisation levels above O1 the test fails. Lower versions of GCC as well as Clang do not show this issue.
We managed to write a small reproducible sample as follows. This takes a uint64_t and gives back a pointer to an array of uint32_t containing the data from the uint64_t. The expected result is that bar() returns the number 1 as a uint32_t.
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

struct RegisterValue {
    size_t bytes = 8;
    alignas(8) char localValue[16] = {42};
    void set(uint64_t value) {
        uint64_t* view = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(this->localValue);
        view[0] = value;
    }
    uint32_t* getAsVector() {
        if (bytes <= 16) {
            return reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(this->localValue);
        } else {
            static uint32_t t = {0xdeadbeef};
            return &t;
        }
    }
};
extern "C" uint32_t bar() {
    RegisterValue v;
    v.set(0x0000000200000001);
    return v.getAsVector()[0];
}

You can play around with the code in compiler explorer.
Essentially, all the reinterpret_casting is being aggressively optimised by GCC resulting in assembly which simply returns an immediate. This is expected. However, at lower optimisation levels (O1) this returns the expected result (1), but at higher levels (O2, O3) this incorrectly returns 42. What makes this more confusing is almost any change to the source (e.g. removing the if/else leaving the first return in getAsVector()) causes the expected behaviour.
This sounds like UB but we have read CPP Reference: reinterpret_cast and can't confidently say whether this is UB or not. If it is, then we need to update our implementation, if it isn't, this would suggest a compiler bug.
Any insight would be helpful.

"...simply returns an immediate" what does that mean? immediate?

There's a sentence on the cppreference page "If a program attempts to read or modify the stored value of an object through a lvalue(until C++11) glvalue(since C++11) through which it is not type-accessible, the behavior is undefined." Do you understand it?

I am not a C++ expert, but in C this would be a clear strict aliasing violation. I would assume that C++ has inherited these rules, because they are linked to what compiler optimizations are possible.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/17671/24377

The standard way to get bytes in and out of integers is to use memcpy. The compiler knows about this and will optimize it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70138631/17398063

@BoP memcpy was one of the solutions we looked into but would require more setup from the user of the class when calling getAsVector

@463035818_is_not_an_ai the answer Weijun Zhou gave is correct. You can see what I mean through the following link https://godbolt.org/z/1eYs4orKc

If your code uses these constructs that are clearly UB (and have been since C++98 and C89) a lot, then either the original authors weren't aware of the aliasing rule at all or assumed that the compilers wouldn't use it for optimization. Either way, this means that a lot of unidentified code may rely on these wrong assumptions. Trying to fix individual occurrences may not be sufficiently safe. Instead you could accept that the code is non-portable non-standard and require that it be compiled with the -fno-strict-aliasing flag. There are many old open source code bases doing it this way.

Yes, what you are doing is Undefined Behavior, type aliasing violation, because you access your localValue through uint64_t*. According to reinterpret_cast, uint64_t* is type-accessible through char*, but not vice-versa. First part can be fixed with std::memcpy:
void set(uint64_t value) {
    std::memcpy(localValue, &value, sizeof(value));
}

but I don't have any straightforward idea for uint32_t* getAsVector() without introducing additional class fields to hold the results. You could either return const char* and let the user handle uint32 conversion, or return a std::vector<std::uint32_t>.

Thank you. This was one of our solutions but we came to the same conclusion where getAsVector would need more fields or would need to return the data in a different way. Not the end of the world, but would require extensive updating across the code base and slightly more annoying interaction with the class.

TL;DR: first part of the answer contains an issue due to the switch between 32 and 64 bits (thanks to @PasserBy for its valuable comments). An updated snippet is provided at the end.
It is indeed UB.
Beyond the magic numbers for size and alignment (which are more a design issue) you have:
alignas(8) char localValue[16] = {42};

At this point only an array of initialized char exists.
Then
uint32_t* getAsVector() {
        if (bytes <= 16) {
            return reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(this->localValue);
        }...

This implicitely creates (see below about implicit lifetime types) an array of std::uint32_t at the storage location but it's value maybe still be indeterminate. Indeed, if called before any set call only char objects have been initialized. Evaluation of indeterminate value is UB (see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/basic.indet#2, thanks to @user17732522).
Besides, the correct way to tell the compiler that it is actually looking at an object of a different type is with std::launder. Notice that this does not help starting object lifetime, it only tells that we are effectively pointing to an object that exists (it helps the compiler to perform better and more accurate optimizations):
... std::launder(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(this->localValue));

Even if you use your setter:
void set(uint64_t value) {
        uint64_t* view = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(this->localValue);
        view[0] = value;
    }

This implicitely creates an array of std::uint64_t at the storage location and you're initializing its value (yet the std::launder is also missing).
But the issue is that, in the getter, you're looking for std::uint32_t, not std::uint64_t and you initialized none.
Besides, when switching between one type of array and the other, your also triggering UB by trying to reference objects of unrelated types at the same location. It's just not allowed. I've opened another question to check if it possible to "convey" a value representation from a type to another one.
The only ways to map a byte-level value representation would be explicitly with calls to std::memcpy, std::bit_cast or std::start_lifetime_as for instance (see below) but they are some pitfalls too.
<original imperfect answer, improved below>
The correct way to go would be
alignas(std::uint64_t) alignas(std::uint32_t) char localValue[2*sizeof(std::uint64_t)];

(If I'm getting your intent right).
Then, in setter:
std::uint64_t* view = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(this->localValue));

provided that std::uint64_t is indeed implemented as a scalar type (which should be and can be check with is_scalar).
Why is it so: scalar type are implicit lifetime types which means, basically, that they are implicitly created (starting their lifetime) with some operations such as the creation of an array of bytes.
Besides, if I get it write, the std::uint64_t will live as long as its storage (third bullet of end of lifetime).
the std::launder is necessary to explicit to the compiler that an std::uint64 _t effectively exists at the given address.
Also, in getter:
std::uint32_t array[4] = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(this->localValue)); // actual size depends on the need but must match storage size
return array;

The same arguments as above apply (an array is also implicit lifetime type).
Another issue with your code is that you may have an indeterminate value when getting the buffer as an std::uint32 _t without having usedset beforehand, because nothing guarantees that the value representation will be kept.
If you want 42 to be usable as a default initialisation value, you may need a std::start_lifetime_as (c++23) to keep the value representation from the initialization. In this case, it will work because value representation of integers is well defined in c++. It won't be so straightforward for other types.
This also validate the switching between array of 32 bits and single 64 bits.
TWIST: to this day, std::start_lifetime_as is not supported: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23
As a work around you can initialize it with a constexpr static version of set. Maybe a lambda will do also.
<the issue in this answer is that I set 64 bits integer and read uninitialized 32 bits ones>
</original imperfect answer, improved below>

This is the improved answer:
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <new>

struct S {
    alignas(std::uint64_t) alignas(std::uint32_t)
        std::array<std::byte, sizeof(std::uint64_t)> localValue = []() {
            std::array<std::byte, sizeof(std::uint64_t)> init;
            std::uint32_t* val =
                std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(init.data()));
            val[0] = 0;
            val[1] = 42;
            return init;
        }();

    void set(uint64_t value) {
        std::uint32_t* view =
            std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(localValue.data()));
        // not proud of this but well defined IMHO :)
        view[0] = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(value >> 8u*sizeof(std::uint32_t));
        view[1] = static_cast<std::uint32_t>((value << 8u*sizeof(std::uint32_t)) >>
                                             8u*sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    }
    uint32_t* getAsVector() {
        return std::launder(
            reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(localValue.data()));
    }
};

LIVE
In this version arrays of 32 bits integer are guaranteed to live on every paths. Only 32 bits value representation are set.

@DanWeaver I missed a detail in you question: in fact you don't want a single 64 bit integer but 2 32 ones? Why is the setter 64 bits? My answer will have to be updated accordingly but the same reasoning will apply.

@PasserBy fixed, thx.

Apologies, my mistake, it only accepts parameter packs but not multiple arguments for some reason. You can write alignas(std::uint64_t) alignas(std::uint32_t) char ... though.

@PasserBy I saw and updated accordingly, I misread the doc also ;)

Without std::start_lifetime_as, the code will be UB. C++20 implicit lifetime still doesn't preserve values upon creation of new objects, meaning attempting to read the std::uint64_t as std::uint32_t will result in indeterminate values.

@PasserBy I thought I was clear on that point in my paragraph starting with "Another issue with...". But IMHO it's not UB, it's only that the values are indeterminate. (Actually a case for UB if that they were padding bits within the value representation but it won't be the case with integer). I may make the answer clearer on this aspect?

Even if set is called, the value is written as std::uint64_t and read as a std::uint32_t. That is UB without std::start_lifetime_as, or rather, performing lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in v.getAsVector()[0] will be UB.

@PasserBy I see. The work around would be to use a memcpy inplace, hoping for compiler optimisation? My preference would be to manipulate only arrays of 32 bits integer. Yet OP has not answered my comment.

@Oersted Thank you for the in depth answer. The actual code is a bit more dangerous, being templated. The setter is 64 bits for this reproducible example which matches our test case that fails. The real offending code is here: https://github.com/UoB-HPC/SimEng/blob/042307a0f10d3822519dd13bca7fae32b091f71f/src/include/simeng/RegisterValue.hh

@DanWeaver I wrote several posts regarding these idea. Maybe you'll find something closer to your need (search for "Get heap storage" or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78672409/idiom-for-initializing-an-stdarray-using-a-generator-function-taking-the-index/78676552#78676552). These would be OK for the case where all sub-objects are of the same type. But be extra careful about value representation issues (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77988726/stdbit-cast-padding-and-undefined-behavior). Please tell me if this pointers are meaningful.

@DanWeaver also given references will address the case where your objects are not implicit lifetime (basically you'll need placement new or std::construct_at

start_lifetime_as, new or some operation that can start lifetime (e.g. memcpy) are required either way to change the type of memory. Otherwise there is no object of the target type that std::launder's result could refer to. If types are not implicit-lifetime, then only the former works. std::launder does nothing at all to fix aliasing violations. That's not what it is for. Reading an indeterminate value is in almost all cases explicitly UB. Exceptions apply only to std::byte and unsigned char and only in specific cases.

@user17732522 from cppref "Objects of implicit-lifetime types can also be implicitly created by operations that begin lifetime of an array of type std::byte, in which case such objects are created in the array,". AFAIU the bytes array is sufficient to start lifetime of integral types. The catch is that there values are indeterminate until initialized. in absence of padding bits, I don't see reason for UB even if we read these values. Moreover, in my answer I take care of initializing the value before any read. You seem to disagree with that. Can you pinpoint what's wrong with my reasoning?

@user17732522 is the corresponding standard wording: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#13?

@user17732522 btw, I've just look deeper into value representation and I now think that my remark about padding bits is optimistic (see notion of uninitialized-friendly types). Thus I would say that I must not dereference the pointers before having properly initialized the implicitly created objects. Fortunately, I'm doing it (if I haven't missed something else).

@Oersted The std::byte array can implicitly start the lifetime of objects. But that happens exactly once when the lifetime of the array starts. So it can either create an object of type uint64_t or an object of type uint32_t nested within itself. But only one of them. So, the array can (with reinterpret_cast+launder) be used to store a uint32_t or an uint64_t but it must be the same type consistently until some other operation that can create objects is done.

"in absence of padding bits, I don't see reason for UB even if we read these values.": The standard simply states it to be UB, regardless of representations, see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/basic.indet#2. The problems are not with your code, but with OP's which the first part of your answer references.

@user17732522 Thx for the ref. As soon as the bits are never read before initialization, they are not "evaluated" thus there is no UB? Is it correct? I will adjust the part about "indeterminate values" in my answer wrt to your comments.

@Oersted It is not about bits, but value of the object. C++'s semantics is (mostly) defined in terms of objects and their values. Representations of these values only rarely matter. The thing that is undefined is the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on the scalar object which currently holds an indeterminate value. Such a conversion would read the object and "produce" the indeterminate value as a result. Note that read is also a technical term. It produces the value held by the object. Representation of the value doesn't matter. How the indeterminate value is represented doesn't matter.

@Oersted This differs from C, which has an object model closer to the representation in memory. In particular C++ doesn't consider trap representations at all. Instead, situations that would be special cased for trap representations in the C standard are simply always defined as UB in C++. C++ also doesn't make any guarantees about the state of padding bits at all. Operations depending on padding bits which may be well-behaved in C are often UB or have unspecified results in C++.

@user17732522 OK I think that I see that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion can lead to hidden evaluation of indeterminate values. All your precisions are important to explain the UB's in OP codes. Now regarding my last snippet, I can't see where I may evaluate indeterminate values (patching initialization is indeed critical). Am I correct?

@Oersted The last snippet is fine. There is no UB. The only technicality might be that you rely on an implementation detail of std::array<std::byte>, but I do not believe there is any way to implement std::array so that it won't behave as you expect. However, in the last snippet there is no point in aligning for uint64_t (because reinterpreting as one would not work) and there is also not really a point to using a std::byte buffer if it is really supposed to be an array of two uint32_t all the time.

@user17732522. Thanks for all these clarifications and points of attention. Very instructive. I'll take time to clarify my answer.
